# WordNet - Which Java API to use for calculating distance metrics

Tags: java, wordnet

As the title implies, I am looking for a WordNet Java API with which I can quickly test some distance metric algorithms (ex. Resnik, Leacock and Chodorow, etc). I've read the documentation of JWNL, JWI and RiTa, but I'm still not sure if either of these implement these methods.

I could also just use a fast method of calculating density and/or weight, as I've found the formulas for those algorithms and could implement them myself.

I need to use them for a study in which I compare the efficiency of some WordNet algorithms. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

i see the question is rather old, and i don't know if that helps, but it appears RiTa can process some sort of semantic distance between two lemmas:
http://rednoise.org/rita/wordnet/documentation/riwordnet_method_getdistance.htm

Answer (score 0):

RiTa seems to be working perfectly only up to WordNet version 3.

I would recommend the [WordNet Similarity for Java](http://code.google.com/p/ws4j/) project. They offer several sophisticated methods to measure semantic similarity.

Update: RiTa-WordNet version-034 (http://rednoise.org/rita/wordnet) includes/supports WordNet version 3.1.